# CMakeLists - add_definition add double quotes around variable

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to pass a definition in the compiler flags in my C++ project configured with CMake as shown below, as suggested in the post [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-June/014611.html):

```
execute_process(COMMAND git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --tags 
OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VERSION)

add_definitions(-DVERSION="\\"${GIT_VERSION}\\"")
```

I'm seeing a lexing error. How do I add quotes around the variable for compiler definitions?

My desired output is

```
-DVERSION="v1.0"
```

Comment: add_definitions(-DVERSION=\"${GIT_VERSION}\")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the CMake escape character `\` to be *paired with* another character. From the CMake [escape sequences](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) documentation:

> A `\` followed by one of `()#" \#@^` simply encodes the literal character without interpreting it as syntax.

You didn't specify what your expected result should be, but here are a couple options. So, if you're just looking to put double-quotes around the `GIT_VERSION` variable, try this (as @GAVD suggested):

```
# Yields -DVERSION="2.23.0"
add_definitions(-DVERSION=\"${GIT_VERSION}\")
```

You shouldn't even need escape characters for one set of quotes in `add_definitions()`:

```
# Yields -DVERSION="2.23.0"
add_definitions(-DVERSION="${GIT_VERSION}")
```

If you're looking to add **two sets** of double-quotes around the variable, try this:

```
# Yields -DVERSION=""2.23.0""
add_definitions(-DVERSION="\"${GIT_VERSION}"\")
```

If you're trying to get the format shown in your linked [post](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-June/014611.html), try this:

```
# Yields -DVERSION="\"2.23.0"\"
add_definitions(-DVERSION="\\\"${GIT_VERSION}"\\\")
```

Comment: Tried as per suggestion and still see lexing error. 
I'm using Ninja as generator here and CMake version is 3.14.6

Comment: @adsun You have not said what the **specific** lexing error is. Please add this to your question post.

Comment: Tried this : add_definitions(-DVERSION=\"${GIT_VERSION}\")

 | cmake3 --build .
 | ninja: error: build.ninja:614: lexing error

 | line 614:  DEFINES = -DVERSION=\"v1.0
\"


(\" is present in new line. If i put it back in previous line manually, it builds fine.)

Comment: It could be possible that  ${GIT_VERSION} contains a new line. Because simply using hard coded version of add_definition(-DVERSION="foo") builds fine. I checked the build.ninja and it didn't have new line.

Comment: I added a step to strip new line from variable GIT_VERSION and it worked

string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" GIT_VERSION "${GIT_VERSION}")

Thanks for your clear and helpful explanation.